# Is it possible to change the CupertinoTabBar height in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I would like to change the `preferredSize` property of a `CupertinoTabBar`. I realize that this property is read-only, so I tried to:

- include a CupertinoTabBar inside a PreferredSize widget, but I get an error because `CupertinoTabScaffold` is expecting a `CupertinoTabBar` as `tabbar`, then I tried to...
- create a custom tab bar, extending `CupertinoTabBar`, but then I realize that I can't figure out how to override `_kTabBarHeight`

```
class CustomCupertinoTabBar extends CupertinoTabBar {
  static const double _kTabBarHeight = 72.0;

  CustomCupertinoTabBar()
      : super(
            // my properties here
      )

  @override
    Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(_kTabBarHeight);

  // more code here
}
```

There is a way to modify the height of this widget?

Answer (score 0):

If we enter the CupertinoTabBar implementation we can see that the property that defines the height of this component is a constant, _kTabBarHeight, that follows the iOS design line. If what you want is to have a custom navigation bar, you might have to find another Widget that suits your need. What do you want to render in the TabBar?

For example, if you use BottomNavigationBar inside a Scaffold, you can modify its iconSize property and the height adapts to this parameter.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
  iconSize: 30,
  showUnselectedLabels: true, ...
```

Comment: `BottomNavigationBar` was my first approach, and design wise I got what I wanted with some padding on the icons and text. I just want some space around the icons and text.
But the overall application structure I am building works better with a `CupertinoTabScaffold`, that needs a `CupertinoTabBar`.
I guess that if I can't override that _kTabBarHeight I will leave it like that.

Answer (score 0):

First you create a CustomTabBar.dart.
After you have to copy all code from `CupertinoTabBar` to CustomTabBar.dart.
Then You just change the number of `_kTabBarHeight` in your class. The default number is `50.0`.
Also you can change `_kTabBarHeight` from CupertinoTabBar class but it not advice.